# Windows Server Usage Tracking

Tags: windows, windows-server-2008, windows-server-2003, windows-server-2008-r2

Let's assume the "Server-A" is a Windows Server v2008 and that is going to be physically decommissioned soon.

Background: There is no clue like anyone is using the server-A or not.  We need a list to reach out to the consuming-clients to get their consent before decommission. Given that how do we collect the active dependency inventory in terms of Web requests, folder accesses, Job-triggers etc.?

(1) I can refer the IIS log to take list of client requests if the server is used as Web Server, Is there any other way to double check the Web requests and where I can gather relevant details like IP, DNS, Last request time and so.

(2) Similarly, how can we verify the shared-folders usage ? I mean, Is any of a client/application/job still be accessing the shared-folders that created in the Server-A? Any Auditing feature exist?

(3) How can we track the triggers to scheduled-jobs in the Server-A? Yes Job logs can be referred, Is there a Windows server that let us those details?

Appreciate if anyone share best practices for these scenarios.Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Let me try to answer your question:
1) Not sure why you are asking this as you already know you can refer to IIS log and most of the info requested is there (source IP, last request time). Alternately you can try using Wireshark to capture on your web service port number as suggest in #2.
2) You may try to use Wireshark to capture the following ports used by Windows share folder (SMB).
TCP : 139,445
UDP: 137,138
 Install the software in the server to capture the traffic.
You might get help [here](https://wiki.wireshark.org/CaptureFilters) on Wireshark capture filter.
3) Not sure what details you are asking for, but schedule jobs can be found in Task Scheduler in Windows, last run date & time, status of last run, history and other info are all here.

Hope my answer helps :)

Answer (score 1):

If this is something you need to do on a regular basis, I would recommend a network analyser tool. There are several on the market. The one I have experience with is [ExtraHop](https://www.extrahop.com/platform/pricing/).

Essentially what these boxes do is they sit on your network and they suck in every single packet that travels over your switches (you feed it spans off your switches, or taps of your uplinks). Then they give you a thorough view of what goes on the network for any host on your network. (some can do way fancier things than that).

If something like a network analyser is out of your budget (and they will be for a lot of SMBs) you can enable NetFlow on your switch. For a small host you'll need fairly regular sampling but essentially if you have something consuming a NetFlow firehose you can get reports of the sessions that the switch sees.

This will tell you the overview of the flows on the network, so you can see that Host A consumed 50Mbps of traffic to Host B for period of time. (If you have NetFlow all the way down you can even see where the traffic went after it left Host B, if Host B is a device that forwards traffic).

It won't give you the insight that a network analysis tool will, as those tools do deep packet inspection and look at usernames, request data, etc. But it's a great start when you're going in blind and have no idea what's going on on the network.

Answer (score 0):

> Is there any other way to double check the Web requests and where I can gather relevant details like IP, DNS, Last request time and so.

The IIS logs are the correct place to look for this. Just make sure, all the applications write them (sometimes they are disabled).

> (2) Similarly, how can we verify the shared-folders usage ?

There is no (easy) auditing itself (except [audit logs](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/install/enabling-the-system-event-audit-log)), but you can use `Get-SmbConnection` to check regularly ([usage here](https://technet.microsoft.com/de-de/library/jj635713(v=wps.630).aspx)).

> How can we track triggers to scheduled-jobs in the Server-A?

You can just have a look in the scheduled tasks (and their history). There is no 'show me all remote triggers that point to me' function, as that would be a bit complicated.